# In PHP, is it possible to type hint two types in the signature of a function?

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there is a way to type hint two type.
after searching online I can't find any thing.

Example

```
class Product {

    public function __contruct(PDO||dbCon $dbCon) {
        // Do What Ever
    }

}
```

So I was wondering if there is something like that **||**

Thanks!

Comment: No, you can't do this. The closest you can get is if they share an interface using that or using the name of a superclass they both inherit from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but if the classes are yours to control you can implement an interface to cover both.

```
interface databaseConnection {...}

class PDO implements databaseConnection {...}

class dbCon implements databaseConnection {...}

class Product {
    public function __construct( databaseConnection $dbCon) {
        // Do What Ever
    }
}
```

If the classes aren't yours you could implement an *adaptor pattern* to make them implement the interface.

```
interface databaseConnectionAdaptor {...}

class PdoDatabaseConnectionAdaptor implements databaseConnectionAdaptor {
    public function __construct( PDO $pdo ) {...}
    ...
}

class DbConnDatabaseConnectionAdaptor implements databaseConnectionAdaptor {
    public function __construct( dbConn $dbCon ) {...}
    ...
}

class Product {
    public function __construct( databaseConnectionAdaptor $dbCon) {
        // Do What Ever
    }
}
```

You may find this will simplify the class Product significantly.

See the Adaptor pattern here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: Wow, Thanks for such a complete answer! This is very very Usefull

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not currently possible in PHP.

Comment: So the only way to actuly make sure if it is the corect type is to use a if that check is_a($dbCon,"PDO")||is_a($dbCon,"dbCon")  Does that seam right ?